# Conversion regex ruby to java

Tags: java, ruby, regex

In ruby I have this

```
ip_address.sub(/\/\d+/,'')
```

Is there any equivalent in java?

Comment: If `ip_address` is a `String` then I'm pretty sure there is an equivalent. I'm no ruby expert so I'd have to guess: what is that meant to do? And what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

`ip_address.replaceFirst("regex", "replacement");`

This is the Java equivalent of Ruby's `sub()`. If you want something like `gsub()`, this other function can be used:

`ip_address.replaceAll("regex", "replacement");`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
/\d+
```

i.e.:

```
ipAddress.replaceAll("/\\d+", "")
```